# If statement on URL wildcard

Tags: javascript, string-matching

How can I accomplish an if statement that says in plain english. If this url that has "W" in it do not show.

I have this.. I just need the wilcard type expression.

```
if (window.location.href == 'http://support.com/support/default.asp?W2297') {
 $(".navi").hide();
}
```

how can i hide some elements if url has `W****` at the end.. i want it to use every url `http://support.com/support/default.asp?W*` that finishes with a W

Comment: you could use : `window.location.href.indexOf('?W') != -1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that with a simple regex. Here's how it works:

```js
var arr = ['http://support.com/support/default.asp?W2297',
           'http://support.com/support/default.asp?W22',
           'http://support.com/support/default.asp?X2297']

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  alert(arr[i] + ': ' + /\?W.+$/.test(arr[i]))
```

**Note:** This regex looks for precisely a question mark ('?') followed by an uppercase 'W' followed by 1 or more characters. If that's not precisely what you need, you'll have to either clarify or correct the regex yourself...

Your code can be:

```
if (/\?W.+$/.test(window.location.href)) {
  $(".navi").hide();
}
```

Comment: Worked great... just realized some have 3 or 2 characters how can this be accomplished? If it startss with W but has a random set of digits after

Comment: @user2752291 I added a few more test cases for you to see how this passes / fails depending on input (including "shorter" endings)

Answer (score 0):

You can say

```
if ( location.href.lastIndexOf( "W" ) > location.href.lastIndexOf( "/" ) ) {
 $(".navi").hide();
}
```

This will hide the `.navi` everytime there is a `"W"` in the request ( `?***` ) part.

More about [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf), if You are interested.